# Oracle Jet how do i create a master detail SPA?

Tags: javascript, router, jet

**Background**

I am trying to write a Single Page Application (SPA) which has a Master -> Detail structure so clicking on items in a screen filter down to other listings/details. 
 For example I have the following

- Category List: lists categories of food (i.e. dairy, meat etc).  When you click on one of these category the list of categories is to be replaced with the Recipe List
- Recipe List : displays a list of recipes for food in the Category selected. On clicking a recipe the Recipe List is replaced with the Recipe Details
- Recipe Details : displays the details for the selected recipe

I am trying to write this with Oracle Jet. I have created 3 modules

- CategoryListModule and CategoryListItemModule (takes a categoryId)
- RecipeListModule (takes a categoryId) and RecipeListItemModule (takes a recipeId)
- RecipeDetailsModule (takes a recipeId)

In each module, it uses a 3rd party library to get data from the server.  For the first 2 modules, the main module gets a basic the list of items to display (i.e. CategoryList  gets the list of category IDS) and its sub-module gets the full information for that specific item (for example CategoryListItemModule calls the server to get all the display information for that category)

*CategoryListModule.html*

```
<oj-bind-for-each data="[[categoryIds]]" as="categoryId">
    <template>
        <div data-bind="ojModule: 
              {name: 'CategoryListItemModule', 
               params:{categoryId: categoryId} }">
        </div>                
    </template>
</oj-bind-for-each>
```

*CategoryListItemModule.html*

```
<div >
    <div data-bind="text:categoryTitle"></div>
    <div data-bind="text:text:categoryDescription"></div>
</div>
```

*Router in main.js*

I have created a Router in my main.js as follows

```
self.router = oj.Router.rootInstance;
    self.router.configure({
        'categoryList': 
            {label: 'CategoryListModule', 
             value: 'CategoryListModule', 
             isDefault: true},
        'recipeList': 
            {label: 'RecipeListModule', 
             value: 'RecipeListModule'},
        'recipeDetails': 
            {label: 'RecipeDetailsModule', 
            value: 'RecipeDetailsModule'}
    });

    var viewModel = {
        router: router
    }

    Bootstrap.whenDocumentReady().then(
        function() {
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
        }
    );
```

**ISSUE**

I do not know how to code the user clicking on a specific category and take the user to the recipe list.

In Vue/Angular/React I coded it with a link around the html for the Category List Item that told the router where to go, for example in Vue it was something like the following

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'recipesList', params: { categoryId: categoryId}}">      
    <div>{{categoryTitle}}</div>
    <div>{{categoryDescription}}</div>
</router-link>
```

I see examples with the Router, but it seems tied to Jet Components which I am not using. For example, in the Cookbook it has the Simple Router example

```
HTML
<oj-bind-for-each data="[[router.states]]">
    <template>
        <oj-option value="[[$current.data.id]]">
            <span><oj-bind-text value="[[$current.data.label]]"></oj-bind-text></span>
        </oj-option>
    </template>
</oj-bind-for-each>

JAVA SCRIPT
var router = Router.rootInstance;
router.configure(
{
  'pref':  { label: 'Preface',   value: 'This is the Preface.',
             isDefault: true },
  'chap1': { label: 'Chapter 1', value: 'This is Chapter 1.' },
  'chap2': { label: 'Chapter 2', value: 'This is Chapter 2.' },
  'chap3': { label: 'Chapter 3', value: 'This is Chapter 3.' }
});

var viewModel =
{
  router: router
};
```

I presume in this example Oracle Jet framework is handling on the onclick of an item in the lists by the "oj-option" component as i see no "onClick" code anywhere.

I see you can do event binding in Jet and in code instigate the router to route but I am sure this can not be the correct solution (for example, i could wrap my html with a  or  and have an onClick listener in the JavaScript to tell the router to go to the next screen.

Any suggestions on how to implement such navigation would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have got a lot further with this. I have found out how you can use code to tell the router to route. So in my "CategoryListItemModule.html" I have added an "onClick" to the div

```
<div on-click="[[onClicked]]>
    <div data-bind="text:categoryTitle"></div>
    <div data-bind="text:text:categoryDescription"></div>
</div>
```

I have changed my router config in "main.js" to

```
self.router = oj.Router.rootInstance;
    self.router.configure({
        'categoryList': 
            {label: 'CategoryListModule', 
             value: 'CategoryListModule', 
             isDefault: true},
        'recipeList/{id}': 
            {label: 'RecipeListModule', 
             value: 'RecipeListModule'},
        'recipeDetails': 
            {label: 'RecipeDetailsModule', 
            value: 'RecipeDetailsModule'}
    });
```

In "CategoryListItemModule.js" I get the router and implement the "onClicked" method

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'ojs/ojrouter', 'knockout', '],
function (oj, Router, ko) {
    function AViewModel(params) {
        ....
        router = Router.rootInstance;
        ....
        this.onClicked= function(event) {
            router.go('recipes/'+ categoryId);
        }
        ....
    };
   ....
```

Now when the user clicks on a specific category in the category list (with say id 123), the "onClicked" function is called which tells the router to route to "/recipeList/123 which should load the RecipeListModule with the ID 123 accessible from inside that module.

However this is still not working correctly as the Jet fails to find RecipeListModule .js/RecipeListModule.html as the path it uses to try and find those files in my project has an extra "recipes" in the path.  I have logged the following separate for this issue to simply this final piece.

[Oracle Jet routing is adding extra folder in path when trying to get child module files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490944/oracle-jet-routing-is-adding-extra-folder-in-path-when-trying-to-get-child-modul)

Comment: I have added the "UPDATE" section in my question as I have got further, however I am still stuck on the complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update in my original post shows the solution for creating a master -> detail SPA.

The remaining issue i had which i put in a separate post has a solution also.